# Float:left prevents click on <a href> tag

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to get a website up and I'm using CSS to get it designed but I am unfamiliar with navbars and getting stuff side by side. I used a "float: left" for my image (logo) and well the text aligned but, it seems like I cannot fully click on the image anymore since it's also something that can be clicked using the  tag. So, any ideas? My code:

**CSS:**

```
#navbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.7;
        display: fixed;
}

#navbar img {
        opacity: 1;
        float: left;
}

#navbar img:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
}

#navbar img a
{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

#navbar ul
{
        position: relative;
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding: 8px 0 0 0;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
}

#navbar ul a
{
        display:block;
        width:60px;
}

#navbar li
{
        display:inline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar"> 
     <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"/></a> 
     <ul> <li>Hello</li> <li>World</li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Post a complete example please, including the HTML.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no such thing as `display: fixed` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Give the navbar a width and a height in css too, also, that display:fixed should be position:fixed;

Comment: Woops, I'm a bit off, did this pretty late. But, I'm still not sure how it'll change my problem as it still exists. Any ideas? ~


   <div id="navbar">

    <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"/></a>

    <ul>

     <li>Hello</li>
     <li>World</li>
    
    </ul>

   </div>

Comment: Hi . i have provided an answer. Kindly let me know whether it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please see the below html and css

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">  
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#"><img src="logo.png"/></a></li>    
        <li>Hello World</li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.7;        
}

#navbar img {
        opacity: 1;

}

#navbar img:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
}

#navbar img a
{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

#navbar ul li
{

        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding: 8px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5em;
}



#navbar ul li
{
        display:inline-block;
}
```

Please check the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Luncqwn3/3/

I have cleaned up your html and css

- I have placed the logo ,as well as the text in the `ul li` and given
  `display:inline-block` which will make them appear next to each other
  in a single line.
- Please try using hexadecimal codes for color like #000 or #fff
  instead of specifying white,black,green etc.
- There is no such thing as display:fixed, please see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)
  site for better understandong.
- I removed `float:left` for the `img` tag , because i achieved
  bringing the logo and text next to each pther using
  `display:inline-block` for the `ul li`.